# Result names in modeler processing tools

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

the results of the modeler (processing tools) do not have the defined names. Is that an issue? For instance: When I'm using "clip grid with polygon" and I define the result name "clip". I expect the result "clip.tif". The result name is "OUTPUTALGSAGACLIPGRIDWITHPOLYGON1.tif". In Qgis Dufour it worked fine. Do I have to change any settings to make it work?

Comment: Which QGIS version are you using? I tested this on QGIS 2.6.0 and it works fine - I can set the result name in the **Output<OutputRaster>** of the function or set the result name when running the model. I don't think there's any settings to change.

Comment: I'm using 2.6.0. When I'm running the model and I define inside the model builder the resultname it doesn't work. But when I define a name in the checkbox while using the model it works. I don't want to write output names into the boxes when I'm using the models.

Comment: Perhaps others can replicate this problem. I still get a result name if I run the model and output as a temporary file. Very strange.